# Missing date and extension with log4net

Tags: log4net

I've just downloaded log4net via NuGet in VS2010.  Log4net version 1.2.11.0.

My issue - I can't append the date or extension to the file name.

Here's my appender:

```xml
<appender name="ErrorAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">

  <file value="Logs\Error" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <datePattern value=".yyyy-MM-dd.lo\g" />

  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <acceptOnMatch value="true" />

    <levelMin value="ERROR" />
    <levelMax value="FATAL" />
  </filter>

  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern
    value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
  </layout>

</appender>
```

The file is created in the correct directory (./Logs) with name "Error", no extension.

I've also tried datePattern ".yyyy-MM-dd.\l\o\g".

None of the other S.O. questions I've visited have helped.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the line

```
 <staticLogFileName value="false" />
```

For details see 
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.StaticLogFileName.html